# Is it possible to initialize a const char* member as a composite of char arrays?

Tags: c++

This should be simple:

I have a static const char* member on my class. I would like to initialize it as a composite string. For example:

```
const char* s_firstPart = "Hello I'm the first part.";
const char* s_secondPart = "I'm the second part.;

struct MyClass
{
  static const char* s_theFinalString;
}

const char* MyClass::s_theFinalString = "Here is the string: " \
    + s_firstPart ++ s_secondPart; // obviously this won't compile
```

My question is: Is there a way of initializing const char* members as composite char arrays?

Comment: No, you can't. You should use `std::string` instead. Something similar to what you want can be managed with macros, but shouldn't be done.

Comment: The important question here is "Why do you have a `const char*`" member, is it not?

Comment: Maybe the fact that you can concatenate string *literals* would help. You can write `"XYZ" "ABC"` and this is the same as `"XYZABC"`. This only works with literals though, not for variable names.

Comment: I'm with Dauphic on this one. Strings are a better option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct answer came from @dauphic in the comments:

> No, you can't. You should use std::string instead. Something similar to what you want can be managed with macros, but shouldn't be done.